# Inverse of function $f : \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Matthew Szudzik's [mapping function](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) is another approach on mapping $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, however, I have trouble finding the inverse of it. The function is
$$f(a, b)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}a^2+a+b&\mbox{, if }a\geq b\\a+b^2&\mbox{, else}\end{array}\right.$$

He states that the inverse of it is
$$f^{-1}(c)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}(c-\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor^2,\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor)&\mbox{, if } c - \lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor^2<\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor\\(\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor, c-\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor^2-\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor)&\mbox{, else}\end{array}\right.$$

But, how did he find it?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Look at cantor's pairing function, which is reversible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: As far as I can see, $f(0,0) = 0^2+0+0 = 0$ (since $0\ge 0$), and $f(1,-2) = 1^2+1+(-2)=0 = f(0,0)$ (since $1\ge -2$). So the function as given doesn't seem to be invertible. Looking at the linked document, I think it is actually meant as function $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ (in which case $(-1,2)$ is clearly not in the domain).

Comment: @celtschk Sorry, I forgot to change that in the last edit. It's fixed now.

Comment: @NaCl: You also forgot to change the title; now that it is clear that's what you meant, I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(a,b) = a^2 + a + b=c; a\ge b$

$f(a,b) = a+b^2=c; a< b$.

So make wild guesses.  If $a' = -b'$ we have $f(a',b) = a'^2 = c$ so $g(c) = (\sqrt{c}, -\sqrt{c})$ will work if $c$ is a perfect square.  But obviously $c$ needn't be a perfect square.  But we can be close.

Suppose $n^2 \le c < (n+1)^2$ or in other words $n \le \sqrt{c}< n+1$.  Then $c = n^2 + n + (c-n^2 - n)$.  If $c-n^2 -n \le n$ we'd have $f(n,(c-n^2 -n)) = c$.  $n^2 < c < (n+1)^2\implies 0< c - n^2<(n+1)^2 -n^2 = (n+1 +n)(n+1 -n) = 2n+1 \implies 0\le c-n^2 < 2n + 1\implies c-n^2-n < n + 1\implies c-n^2 -n \le n$.

So $g(c) = (\lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor, c - \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor^2 - \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor)$ will do.  But this requires $ c - \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor^2 - \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor)\in \mathbb N$. i.e $ c - \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor^2 > \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor) $

Other wise we must  solve for $f(a,b) = a+b^2=c; a< b$ first.

If $n^2 \le c < (n+1)^2$ then $f(c-n^2, n) = c$ if $c-n^2 < n$.  As $n^2 \le c < n^2 + 2n+1$ we know $0\le c-n^2 < 2n+1$.

So $h(c) = (c -  \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor^2 , \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor)$ will do if $c -  \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor^2>0$ which only fails if $n^2 \le c < n^2 + 1$ .  If this is the case then $c -  \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor^2 < 1 \le  \lfloor \sqrt{c} \rfloor$.

Comment: $f(10,4) = 10^2+10+4 = 114 \not= 26$

Comment: Doh.  That was a very stupid mistake.  Um is this injective after all?  Probably, considering the day i'I'm having.  Still, getting the inverse seems pretty straightforward.  Actually he maybe started with the inverse for all we know.